# Is there a way to create a Fragment of a generic class in Android?

Tags: java, android-fragments, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

Basically, my problem comes down to the fact that a method in an abstract superclass can not be both abstract and static (i.e. static methods can't be overridden in Java), and thus I can't "assert" that my custom-written Fragment has the method "newInstance(HashMap) if all the code knows is that what it's trying to create is a Fragment.

That was really confusing probably, so let me try to explain in detail.
I have some code that automatically creates a series of Fragments to display based on an ArrayList "parameterList" of HashMaps. (I.e. parameterList.get(3) would be the parameters for the 3rd fragment).

```
public void setupFragments()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    ...
    for(HashMap<StringObject> fragmentParams : parameterList){
        createNewFragment(...)
    }
}

private void createNewFragment(...){
    ...
}
```

I have several different types (classes) of Fragments that all inherit from an abstract class called "GameFragment" that itself extends Fragment.

What I would like to be able to do is to add to the parameters of any given fragment the class/type of the Fragment. I.e. something like this:

```
public class ATypeOfFragment extends GameFragment{...}

public class AnotherTypeOfFragment extends GameFragment{...}

public abstract class GameFragment extends Fragment{...}
```

```
public void setupFragments()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, Object> firstFragmentParams = new Hashmap<>();
    firstFragmentParams.put("fragmentType", ATypeOfFragment.class);
    parameterList.add(firstFragmentParams);


    HashMap<String, Object> secondFragmentParams = new Hashmap<>();
    firstFragmentParams.put("fragmentType", AnotherTypeOfFragment.class);
    parameterList.add(secondFragmentParams);


    for(HashMap<StringObject> fragmentParams : parameterList){
        createNewFragment((Class<GameFragment>) fragmentParams.get("fragmentType"))
    }
}

private void createNewFragment(Class<GameFragment> class){
    ...
}
```

Now the problem is - Is there any way to make this work? Is there a way I can write the function createNewFragment where it will create a Fragment of the specified class?

Firstly, I don't understand generic classes very well yet (As you can probably tell).

Secondly, another problem here is that because it is an Android Fragment, I can't change or even call the constructor. Android Fragments are instantiated via the use of a static "newInstance(...)" function.

Now you might start to see the problem. What I would like to do is to have an abstract static method "newInstance(...)" in GameFragment (or another interface if necessary) so my createNewFragment function can just call "class.newInstance(...)".

```
public abstract class GameFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
    public abstract static GameFragment newInstance(...);
}
```

```
private void createNewFragment(Class<GameFragment> class){
    GameFragment newFragment = class.newInstance(...); 
    //Not that this would work anyway, again I don't understand generic classes very well yet
}
```

However, in Java, you can't have a method both be abstract and static.

Is there some alternative way of telling my program that a generic class is guaranteed to have a certain static method?

If not, I'll just create a "dictionary" function that maps certain Strings to the newInstance(...) function of all of my (Game)Fragment classes. However, of course I would prefer not to have to do that type of "housekeeping" whenever I expand on my app with new types of Fragments.